# Is it possible improve the code scanning beyond what SyntaxQ does?

Tags: syntax, debugging

Please, consider this package

```
(* ::Package:: *)
BeginPackage["HelloWorld`"];
a::usage="A";
b::usage="B";
Begin["`Private`"];
a=1;
b=
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Obviously, on the seventh line something is missing ( regarding the programmer's real intentions ...). Nevertheless

```
SetDirectory @ NotebookDirectory[];
Needs["HelloWorld`", "HelloWorld.m"]
a + b
```

does not rise any warning and returns

```
1 + HelloWorld`Private`
```

If I see rightly, the reason is that `End` "*... returns the present context, and reverts to the previous one.*", therefore the package content, as a whole, is syntactically correct and the result is exactly what one should await for. In effect

```
SyntaxQ @ Import["HelloWorld.m", "Text"]
```

and

```
Position[
 SyntaxQ /@ Import["HelloWorld.m", "Lines"]
 , False
 ]
```

respectively give `True` and `{{7}}`. Now the question is: "
Putting apart merely sintactic consideration, all aforementioned undisclose an objective complication in error detection; how can code be more deeply scanned ?".

A coarse example, tailored for this circustance, can clarify what I'm trying to say: by means of

```
sintaxQ[string_String] := Module[{ret, str, lines, check},
   str = StringTrim[string];
   If[SyntaxQ[str], Null, Return["error 1"]];
   lines = StringTrim /@ StringSplit[str, "\n"];
   check = TrueQ @(Cases[lines, _?SyntaxQ] != lines);
   If[check, Return["error 2"]];
   Return[ret];
   ];
sintaxQ @ Import["HelloWorld.m", "Text"]
```

we get

```
"error 2"
```

Please, consider that the `b=` trouble presented in the question is nothing more than the most basic example inspiring the search for a smarter scanner. I'm not asking about a way to solve this childish example.

Comment: `sintaxQ@"Module[{x=1},` newline `x` newline `]"`.

Comment: Please, consider that the `b=` trouble presented in the question is nothing more than the most basic example inspiring the search for a smarter scanner. I'm not asking about a way to solve this childish example.

Comment: I don;t know how but maybe someone else will be able to help you. Maybe this will be of some use too. You can import a package step by step with `Read[stream, Hold[Expression]]`. And do pattern matching if you find this more convenient.